# NGINX 502 Bad Gateway error inside Docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, bad-gateway

I haven't had any issues with my Docker container or NGINX until today where I am getting a random unexpected 502 Bad Gateway error even though I have made no changes to my configuration files, Docker files, or any other file in my project.

The 502 error from `/var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log`:

```
9.160.81.63 - - [25/Mar/2022:20:40:50 +0000] "GET /api/get_info HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "https://example.com:4000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.82 Safari/537.36"
```

The error message from `/var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log`:

```
[error] 26#26: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 9.160.81.63, server: , request: "GET /api/get_info HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://0.0.0.0:5000/api/get_info", host: "example.com:4000", referrer: "https://example.com:4000/"
```

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 8765 ssl default_server;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.html;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example_project/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/example_project/key.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/example_project/dhparam.pem;

  ssl on;
  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_timeout 60m;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

  location /api {

    proxy_pass          https://0.0.0.0:5000/api;

    proxy_redirect      default;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host:4000;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

  }
}
```

This is all running on a `node:15.7.0-alpine3.10` container which is also using `nginx:stable-alpine`. Again, I've never faced this error before and I've committed zero new changes to my project. Why is this error occurring now and how do I fix it?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a pseudo IP and not "real". There for cant be used as target for `proxy_pass`. BTW: If selinux is enabled, its forbidden for Webserver to create client connections, disable it temporary  for testing.

Comment: @Marc I replaced `0.0.0.0` with `127.0.0.1` and I still get the same error. SELinux was already disabled too.

Comment: What happens if you "curl" the url, `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/api`?

Comment: @Marc I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000 after 0 ms: Connection refused`.

Comment: Then you application is not running

Comment: @Marc How do I fix that? `5000` is the default port for Flask.

Comment: I dont know, perhaps start your app?

Comment: @Marc What do you mean start my app? The website is up but fails to make a call from frontend to backend.

Comment: Exactly what i have said. If you are on the server and cant even connect there to your app its either not running or on a diffrent port. What does `netstat -ln4t` output?

Comment: @Marc I get `netstat: unrecognized option: 4`.

Comment: @Marc I get `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8765            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: Is that all?! From where did you issue the command? Add your docker config(s)